# Pause and Resume AnimatorSet Api < 19

Tags: android, android-animation

i want to pause and resume a  animator set(all of the animatons in the animator set run sequentially).
i have written this code ,but it doesn't work properly(doesn't resume from the same place) :

```
   AnimatorSet animatorSet;
   int startPosition = 0 ;
   long playTime = 0;
    public void playOrResume(Marker marker, List<LatLng> positions, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
            @Override
            public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
            }
        };

        animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        Animator previous = null;
        for (int i = startPosition ; startPosition < positions.size(); i++) {
            LatLng finalPosition = positions.get(i);
            Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
            ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
            if (previous != null) {
                animatorSet.play(animator).after(previous);
            } else {
                animator.setCurrentPlayTime(playTime);
                animatorSet.play(animator);
            }
            previous = animator;
        }
        animatorSet.setDuration(300);
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        ArrayList<Animator> animators = animatorSet.getChildAnimations();
        for(int i= 0 ; i < animators.size() ; i++) {
            Animator animator = animators.get(i);
            if (animator.isStarted()){
                startPosition = i;
                playTime = animator.getCurrentPlayTime();
                animatorSet.cancel();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the animations in the AnimatorSet are all ValueAnimator/ObjectAnimators, you can use `ValueAnimator.getCurrentPlayTime()` to track the playing position of the on-going animator in the set before you cancel it. When you resume the set, you can then call `ValueAnimator.setCurrentPlayTime(long)` to restore the play position of the unfinished animator in the new set. The two APIs mentioned above were both introduced in API level 11.

```
   AnimatorSet animatorSet;
   int startPosition = 0 ;
   long playTime = 0;
    public void playOrResume(Marker marker, List<LatLng> positions, final LatLngInterpolator latLngInterpolator) {
        TypeEvaluator<LatLng> typeEvaluator = new TypeEvaluator<LatLng>() {
            @Override
            public LatLng evaluate(float fraction, LatLng startValue, LatLng endValue) {
                return latLngInterpolator.interpolate(fraction, startValue, endValue);
            }
        };

        if (animatorSet == null) {
            Animator previous = null;
            for (int i = startPosition ; startPosition < positions.size(); i++) {
                LatLng finalPosition = positions.get(i);
                Property<Marker, LatLng> property = Property.of(Marker.class, LatLng.class, "position");
                ObjectAnimator animator = ObjectAnimator.ofObject(marker, property, typeEvaluator, finalPosition);
                if (previous != null) {
                    animatorSet.play(animator).after(previous);
                } else {
                    animatorSet.play(animator);
                }
                previous = animator;
            }
        } else {
           // Reuse the old animators so the start values are not changed.
           List<Animator> anims = animatorSet.getChildAnimations().subList(startPosition, positions.size() - 1);
           // Restore the play time of the first animator.
           anims.get(0).setCurrentPlayTime(playTime);
           animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
           animatorSet.playSequentially(anims);
        }
        animatorSet.setDuration(300);
        animatorSet.start();
    }

    public void pause() {
        ArrayList<Animator> animators = animatorSet.getChildAnimations();
        for(int i= 0 ; i < animators.size() ; i++) {
            Animator animator = animators.get(i);
            if (animator.isStarted()){
                startPosition = i;
                playTime = animator.getCurrentPlayTime();
                animatorSet.cancel();
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @AHoneyBustard it's not just one animator , it's a AnimatorSet

Comment: Yes, but there's only one on-going animator at any given time in this animator set. You need to find that one, and save/restore the play time, so the resume is seamless. @Reza

Comment: @AHoneyBustard i added it , still same result

Comment: @DorisLiu sorry for worng mentioning

Comment: @ReZa you are adressing the wrong person, your comments should refer to Doris Liu ;)

Comment: No worries. :) So what do you see when you "resume"? @ReZa

Comment: @DorisLiu same as before. the animation starts from behind the right location.

Comment: I think I found the issue: you need to make sure the ObjectAnimator that you recreated has the same start value as before it was "paused". Otherwise restoring the play time wouldn't make sense. Current code use where the last animation left of as the new start value, as it reads the start value from the property. That needs to be changed

Comment: @DorisLiu i didn't get it ;) can you show it with code ?

Comment: @DorisLiu thanks man . i will test and let you know tommarow.

Comment: @DorisLiu it doesn't even compile .

Comment: what does the compiler complain?

Comment: @DorisLiu on this line : anims.get(0).setCurrentPlayTime(playTime); can not resolve method setCurrentPlayTime

Comment: You need to cast that animator to an ObjectAnimator.

Comment: Try ((ObjectAnimator) anims.get(0)).setCurrentPlayTime(playTime); instead

Comment: @DorisLiu I find only ValueAnimator has the method setCurrentPlayTime. ObjectAnimator doesn't have the same method. How could you cast some animator to ObjectAnimator and still get touch to setCurrentPlayTime method? 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator#setCurrentPlayTime(long)
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ObjectAnimator

Comment: @DorisLiu Sorry that I didn't find that ObjectAnimator is subclass of ValueAnimator.